# How to get path of file from which folder it is browse in ASPxUploadControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, file-upload

I want to get file path of uploaded file. I have excel file in folder and in excel file I have files name which is also in same folder. I am trying to upload only excel file. It uploaded successfully but cannot get uploaded file path. On the base of file path I have to get all the files whose name are in excel file. I am trying this code... Please help me in this regard.

```
protected void ASPxUploadControl1_FileUploadComplete(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadControl.FileUploadCompleteEventArgs e)
{
   String strFilename = e.UploadedFile.FileName;
   String strPath = Path.GetFullPath(e.UploadedFile.FileName);
   DirectoryInfo hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch = new DirectoryInfo(strPath);    
}
```

Comment: Do you mean uploaded path at the server where you were uploading to? If not, you cannot access client file system.

Comment: I want to access the client system path or directory name from where he will upload file. Is there any way that I can achieve this.

Comment: this would be a security issue. you cannot do it

Answer (score 0):

An ASPxUpload control will save to App_Data/UploadTemp and then you decide where the file is saved to when you do this:

```
e.UploadedFile.SaveAs(m_fullpath, true);  //true means overwrite
```

The uploaded file can be used to get .xls files by doing this:

```
string m_filename = e.UploadedFile.FileName;
string m_extension = Path.GetExtension(m_filename);
```

So you can do something like...

```
if(m_extension == ".xls")
{
  e.UploadedFile.SaveAs(m_fullpath, true); 
}
```

The better approach is to set the file types that are allowed in the upload control.

```
<ValidationSettings AllowedFileExtensions=".xls, .xlsx"></ValidationSettings>
```

Comment: But I want to get client system path or directory from where he will upload file. Let say I have excel file in this directory D:\File. when I will upload file from D:\File I want to get path D:\File in aspxUploadControl.

Comment: I see.  Modern browsers will not let you get that information because of security.  See this for example:  http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q259544

Comment: Is there any way that I do this?

Comment: An upload control is not going to allow you to do what you want to do.  You would have to make something custom.  Even then I am not sure it will work. You will have to do something like this at some point.  Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xls", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

Comment: I set internet explorer as default browser and run my web application now I am getting complete by using string filePath = e.UploadedFile.PostedFile.FileName;